# Bizarre behavior of exec() in PHP

Tags: php, exec

I'm still a newbie in PHP, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here.

So, I'm calling some back-end scripts which produce lines of text, and I thought I'd tinker around with `exec` to make sure it works correctly.  Of course, in the (Linux) shell, an easy multiline output command is something like

```
echo a;echo b;echo c
```

which, of course, produces what one would expect:

```
a
b
c
```

So, why am I getting an extra "c" when I run `exec` below?

input:

```
exec("echo a;echo b;echo c",$output,$return);
echo("return: $return\n");
echo("count: ". count($output) . "\n");
foreach($output as $i)
  {print "$i\n";}
var_dump($output);
```

output:

```
return: 0
count: 4
a
b
c
c
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Now, I know that `exec` returns the last line processed, but I didn't echo the return value of `exec`.  And what makes this even more puzzling is that if I make the strings a bit more "random", it seems to work correctly:

```
jmaney> php -r 'exec("echo asfd;echo asdfasf;echo grrrr",$output,$return);echo("return: $return\n");echo("count: ". count($output) . "\n");foreach($output as $i){print "$i\n";}var_dump($output);'
return: 0
count: 3
asfd
asdfasf
grrrr
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "asfd"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "asdfasf"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "grrrr"
}
```

What am I missing here?

**Edited to add:**  I'm running bash shell version 3.2.48, SUSE Enterprise Linux version 11, Linux Kernel version 2.6, and PHP version 5.2.12.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Running your exact code only produces 3 items in `$output`

Comment: Your first code is outputting just what it should

Comment: Really?  Then why does "c" show up twice when I print out the elements of `$output`, and why doesn't "grrrr" show up twice in the second example?

Comment: Seconded, I executed the exact code posted (less the `'` mark at the end of the last `var_dump` and got only three items (correctly)

Comment: Oops!  The `'` has been edited out (it was, of course, left over from when I copied and pasted from the console).

Comment: Well, the fact that this isn't easily reproduced is a bit troubling....I'll forward this question to some of my coworkers (who are much more well-versed in programming than I am) and see what they make of it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. What shell are you running? What version of php?

Comment: Bash shell version  3.2.48, SUSE Enterprise Linux version 11, Linux Kernel version 2.6, and PHP version 5.2.12.

Comment: @Jack are you sure the you have include ALL the code that response for this problem?

Comment: Well, it seems as though using backticks (aka `shell_exec`) produces the right output.  I'd like to be able to easily capture the return value...I guess I can call `$?` directly from the shell.  Still, it would be nice to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: @ajreal Yes, I've ran the code above on the command line (via `php -r`).  The code examples consist of the entire inputs and outputs given to and received from the console.  Even if I add `unset($return);unset($output);` to the beginning of the code, an extra "c" is still produced...

Comment: Try surrounding your strings with quotes?

Comment: I just tried it.  Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try to do something exec("echo a > some_file;echo b >> some_file;echo c >> some_file",$output,$return); and look at some_file to see was last command realy executed two times or it is some PHP output bug.

Comment: As expected, `c` is written only once in `some_file`.  Have I really found a bug in PHP?  You'd think that something so simple would've been found by now...

Comment: I doubt you found a bug if everyone else get expected results(including me). But your case is interesting, can you try to localise error? FOr example echo only two or more then three chars, echo different chars, try patthru(), try to debug with xdebug, try different system output(for example printf), try to upgrade/recompile PHP etc.

Comment: Executing the same code ("a","b","c") on PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 with Suhosin-Patch correctly produces three lines of output.  FYI.

Comment: weird, I cannot reproduced this too!

Comment: php 5.2.12 produces the output described, php 5.3.2 does not.

Comment: Downvoter:  Care to explain, especially since the error above points to an official bug in PHP 5.2.12?

Comment: Oh goodie, more serial downvoters. Are you done throwing your temper tantrum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, is a bug that was patched in php 5.2.13 (Bug #50732 exec() adds single byte twice to $output array https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50732)